# How to use read -ra inline?

Tags: bash, python

I need to run a command from python so I'm doing:

```
os.system('IFS=".";for f in data/* ; do read -ra ADDR <<< "$f";     mv "$f" "data/${ADDR[-1]}"; done;')
```

but it says :

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

But if I run this in bash it works fine:

```
IFS="."
for f in data/* 
do 
    read -ra ADDR <<< "$f"
    mv "$f" "data/${ADDR[-1]}"
done;
```

It works just fine. How can I fix it to work in one line?

Comment: I think you should put a semicolon before `do`

Comment: @sudodus that was not the problem.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that `os.system` invokes `/bin/sh` rather than `bash` - it won't understand `read -ra` *or* the here-string operator `<<<`

Comment: @sudodus I want to run it from within python

Comment: @steeldriver isn't sh redirected to bash?

Comment: Use subprocess  module instead of os.

Comment: Usually `sh` is a symlink to the `dash` shell - you can check with `ls -l $(which sh)` for example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@steeldriver has pinpointed the problem. You could solve it with:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['bash', '-c', '''
    IFS="."
    for f in data/*; do
        read -ra ADDR <<< "$f"
        [[ ${#ADDR[@]} -gt 0 ]] && mv "$f" "data/${ADDR[-1]}"
    done
'''])
```

but at this point, you're probably better just doing the whole thing in python instead of calling out to bash: something like

```
for f in os.scandir("data"):
    if f.is_file():
        addr = f.name.split(".")[-1]
        if f.name != addr:
            os.rename(f.path, "data/"+addr)
```

Comment: I agree with this pure-python approach.

Comment: But I have a huge number of files. isn't my bash approach faster?

Comment: Why should I use subprocess instead of os?

Comment: `os.system` only takes a single string as an argument, so you have to quoting games like toliveira's answer. `subprocess.run` takes a list of strings. As for performance, you'd have to benchmark it, but I would be surprised if the bash version is faster.

Comment: @glennjackman your subprocess code gives me arror

Comment: subprocess.run(['bash', '-c', '
                                  ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: Try using triple quotes for the bash script body

Answer (score 1):

Following @steeldriver comment and @glenn jackman answers:

```
os.system('/bin/bash -c \'IFS=".";for f in data/* ; do read -ra ADDR <<< "$f";     mv "$f" "data/${ADDR[-1]}"; done; \' ')
```

Comment: If you are not sure that bash is in /bin/bash, use just bash instead of /bin/bash.